# Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for J bigger than 5/2

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, representation-theory

I am supposed to expand $|4,2;\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ as a sum of $|j,\frac{5}{2}\rangle$, getting coefficients from table. I can find them easily for $j=\frac{5}{2} $ and $j=\frac{7}{2}$, but I don't know from where to get values for $j=\frac{9}{2},\frac{11}{2}$. Do you know of any such a source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wolfram|Alpha. The function ClebschGordan[$\{j_1, m_1\}, \{j_2, m_2\}, \{j, m\}$] gives the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient for the decomposition of $|j,m\rangle$ in terms of $|j_1,m_1\rangle|j_2,m_2\rangle$. For instance: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ClebschGordan%5B%7B1,+1%7D,+%7B3%2F2,+1%2F2%7D,+%7B5%2F2,+3%2F2%7D%5D).